# G-WAN: "no listener" error after installation on Ubuntu Server 14.04 with XFS filesystem

Tags: configuration, listener, g-wan

I'm desperately trying to start G-WAN since two days without any progress, so please let me now ask for your gentle help because I'm becoming (more) crazy !

Here is the log after a start with ./gwan -d -w 1

```
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] ------------------------------------------------
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] G-WAN 4.3.14 64-bit (Mar 14 2013 07:33:12)
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] ------------------------------------------------
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] Local Time: Sun, 10 Jan 2016 14:32:58 GMT+1
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] RAM: (7.27 GiB free + 0 shared + 704.00 KiB buffers) / 7.84 GiB total
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] Physical Pages: 7.27 GiB / 7.84 GiB
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] DISK: 115.94 GiB free / 118.47 GiB total
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT]  Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT]  udev           devtmpfs  3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT]  tmpfs          tmpfs     798M  468K  797M   1% /run
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT]  /dev/sda2      xfs       119G  2.2G  116G   2% /
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT]  none           tmpfs     4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT]  none           tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT]  none           tmpfs     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /run/shm
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT]  none           tmpfs     100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT]  /dev/sda1      xfs       186M   46M  141M  25% /boot
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] 162 processes, including pid:5280 './gwan -d -w 1'
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] Page-size:4,096 Child-max:63,605 Stream-max:16
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] CPU: 1x Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU C2750 @ 2.40GHz
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT]  0 id: 0     0
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT]  1 id: 1     1
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT]  2 id: 2     2
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT]  3 id: 3     3
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT]  4 id: 4     4
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT]  5 id: 5     5
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT]  6 id: 6     6
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT]  7 id: 7     7
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] Cores: possible:0-7 present:0-7 online:0-7 
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] L1d cache:   24K line:64     0
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] L1i cache:   32K line:64     0
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] L2  cache: 1024K line:64   0-1
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] NUMA node #1 0-7
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] CPU(s):1, Core(s)/CPU:4, Thread(s)/Core:2
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] Bogomips: 4,800.19
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] Virtualization: VT-x
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] './gwan -w 1' used to override 1 x 4-Core CPU(s)
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT]   using   1 workers 0[00000001]0
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT]   among   8 threads 0[11111111]7
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] 64-bit little-endian (least significant byte first)
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS \n \l (3.13.0-74) 64-bit
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] user: root (uid:0), group: root (uid:0), members: lm4ppdcd
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] system  fd_max: 1,024
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] program fd_max: 1,024
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] updated fd_max: 500,000
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] Available network interfaces (2):
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] 127.0.0.1
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] 62.210.169.132
[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] * no listener in /opt/gwan64

[Sun, 10 Jan 2016 13:32:58 GMT] * child normal exit(1)

[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] * no listener in /opt/gwan64

[Sun, 10 Jan 2016 13:32:58 GMT] * child normal exit(1)

[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] * no listener in /opt/gwan64

[Sun, 10 Jan 2016 13:32:58 GMT] * child normal exit(1)

[Sun Jan 10 13:32:58 2016 GMT] * no listener in /opt/gwan64

[Sun, 10 Jan 2016 13:32:58 GMT] * child died 3 times within 3 seconds
```

I've turned all files and directories under gwan64 to 777 and all of them are now owned by root in the root group.

I've changed the active interface from em1 to eth0 too !

Thanks in advance for your guidance to solve this problem encountered on my new server and kind regards, Germain@ADtlas.com

Hi Law29, here is the result of ls -ltrR /opt/gwan64

```
  /opt/gwan64:
  total 220
  drwxrwxrwx 2 root root     21 Aug 13  2011 fonts
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   5619 Aug 13  2011 license.txt
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    877 Dec 21  2011 hello.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   3138 Jan  6  2012 readme.txt
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   1056 Jan 18  2012 argv.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   1322 Jan 27  2012 main.c__
  drwxrwxrwx 6 root root     56 Dec 25  2012 libraries
  drwxrwxrwx 2 root root   4096 Mar 10  2013 include
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 188152 Mar 14  2013 gwan
  drwxrwxrwx 3 root root     28 Jan  9 18:09 62.210.169.132_80
  drwxrwxrwx 2 root root     47 Jan 10 14:32 logs
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root      0 Jan 10 14:32 gwan_05280.pid
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root      0 Jan 10 14:32 gwan_05286.pid
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root      0 Jan 10 14:32 gwan_05290.pid
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root      0 Jan 10 14:32 gwan_05294.pid
  -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root      0 Jan 10 14:32 Gwan_05279.pid
  -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   6424 Jan 10 14:32 trace

  /opt/gwan64/fonts:
  total 4
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 576 Jul 29  2010 9pts.gif

  /opt/gwan64/libraries:
  total 0
  drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 16 Feb 23  2012 java
  drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 24 Sep  6  2012 cs
  drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 49 Oct  8  2012 tkcabinet
  drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 41 Oct  8  2012 sqlite3

  /opt/gwan64/libraries/java:
  total 0
  drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 39 Oct  8  2012 api

  /opt/gwan64/libraries/java/api:
  total 8
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 370 Feb 23  2012 Gwan.class
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 874 Aug 28  2012 Gwan.java

  /opt/gwan64/libraries/cs:
  total 4
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1501 Sep  6  2012 gwan_api.cs

  /opt/gwan64/libraries/tkcabinet:
  total 320
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 190377 Aug  5  2010 tcutil.h
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  45754 Aug  5  2010 tchdb.h
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  82844 Aug  5  2010 tcfdb.c

  /opt/gwan64/libraries/sqlite3:
  total 288
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20686 Dec  8  2009 sqlite3ext.h
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 268351 Feb  3  2010 sqlite3.h

  /opt/gwan64/include:
  total 112
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1149 Jan  6  2012 short_types.h
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4545 Jan 31  2012 xbuffer.h
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2968 Jun 19  2012 fastcgi.h
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1530 Jan 10  2013 float.h
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   356 Jan 10  2013 varargs.h
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   545 Jan 10  2013 stddef.h
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   180 Jan 10  2013 stdbool.h
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   401 Jan 10  2013 stdarg.h
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27140 Feb 19  2013 gwdbg.h
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46307 Mar 10  2013 gwan.h

  /opt/gwan64/62.210.169.132_80:
  total 0
  drwxrwxrwx 7 root root 64 Jan  3  2013 #62.210.169.132

  /opt/gwan64/62.210.169.132_80/#62.210.169.132:
  total 4
  drwxrwxrwx 2 root root    6 Jan 27  2012 _logs
  drwxrwxrwx 2 root root    6 Apr 20  2012 gzip
  drwxrwxrwx 2 root root  124 Jan  3  2013 handlers
  drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Mar  8  2013 csp
  drwxrwxrwx 3 root root  135 Mar 14  2013 www

  /opt/gwan64/62.210.169.132_80/#62.210.169.132/_logs:
  total 0

  /opt/gwan64/62.210.169.132_80/#62.210.169.132/gzip:
  total 0

  /opt/gwan64/62.210.169.132_80/#62.210.169.132/handlers:
  total 36
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  783 Mar  3  2012 html.c_
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2057 May  4  2012 flv.c_
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9789 May  4  2012 main_generic.c_
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3744 May  4  2012 main_hello.c_
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7226 May  4  2012 main_404_redirect.c_
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2136 May  4  2012 main_restful.c_

  /opt/gwan64/62.210.169.132_80/#62.210.169.132/csp:
  total 592
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1292 Dec  6  2010 argv.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2791 Jul  4  2011 report.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1727 Nov 28  2011 trace.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  8329 Nov 28  2011 captcha.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  6674 Nov 28  2011 data_uri.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   963 Nov 29  2011 exit.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  3125 Dec 17  2011 crash_libc.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2384 Dec 17  2011 crash.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1470 Dec 17  2011 asm.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  3153 Dec 21  2011 crash_gwcall.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2180 Dec 27  2011 email.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1672 Dec 27  2011 div_by_zero.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   898 Dec 31  2011 servlet_name.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1605 Dec 31  2011 sql.c_
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1418 Jan  6  2012 redirect.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1706 Jan  8  2012 hello.m_
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1755 Jan  8  2012 hello.mm_
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2848 Jan  8  2012 gnustep.m__
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1038 Jan 15  2012 100.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2187 Jan 15  2012 base64.c
  drwxrwxrwx 2 root root    48 Jan 15  2012 folder
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23428 Jan 16  2012 sqlite.c_
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53260 Jan 27  2012 kv_bench.c_
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   882 Jan 27  2012 www_csp.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2070 Jan 30  2012 rates.xml
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   802 Feb 23  2012 report.java
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10387 Feb 25  2012 charts.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1293 Mar  4  2012 all.java
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  6759 Mar  5  2012 getheaders.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  8096 Mar  5  2012 forum.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1414 Mar  5  2012 argv.java
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2516 Mar 10  2012 bigtable.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1126 Mar 18  2012 power.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1457 Mar 21  2012 cache.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20943 Mar 29  2012 json.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19191 Apr 11  2012 kv.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11911 Apr 22  2012 loan.java
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2960 Aug 29  2012 cairo.c_
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11074 Sep 12  2012 comet.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  7090 Sep 14  2012 contact.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1423 Sep 15  2012 hellox.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14838 Sep 16  2012 chart.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12005 Sep 16  2012 request.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2915 Sep 16  2012 curl.c_
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  5933 Sep 16  2012 httpdate.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12693 Oct  6  2012 fractal.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  7862 Oct 18  2012 served_from.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2487 Nov 22  2012 persistence.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  6186 Dec  8  2012 tidy.c_
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2565 Dec 10  2012 hello.go
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   738 Dec 11  2012 hello.cs
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2179 Dec 11  2012 hello.pl
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  3395 Dec 11  2012 hello.php
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2260 Dec 11  2012 hello.js
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2347 Dec 11  2012 hello.lua
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2084 Dec 11  2012 hello.py
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2343 Dec 11  2012 hello.rb
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   810 Dec 11  2012 hello.java
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1253 Dec 14  2012 mysql.c_
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  3288 Dec 20  2012 memcached.c_
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  5460 Dec 21  2012 json_bench.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1381 Dec 21  2012 hello.cpp
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1778 Dec 23  2012 throttle.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1747 Dec 25  2012 hello.d_
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   873 Dec 25  2012 hello.scala_
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  3414 Dec 25  2012 rnd.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2457 Dec 25  2012 auth_oauth.c_
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   830 Dec 25  2012 hello.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1043 Dec 25  2012 argv.cs
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1920 Jan  5  2013 cookies.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4062 Jan 25  2013 setheaders.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2389 Jan 25  2013 noheaders.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1231 Jan 28  2013 redirect2.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2832 Feb 13  2013 stream1.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  3130 Feb 13  2013 extern.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  3233 Feb 13  2013 stream2.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  7909 Feb 18  2013 imgsz.c_
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1393 Feb 19  2013 cookie.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12674 Feb 19  2013 entity.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2062 Feb 19  2013 entity_size.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9523 Feb 26  2013 loan.cs
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  7164 Feb 26  2013 loan.php
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12982 Feb 26  2013 loan.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  7832 Feb 26  2013 auth_basic.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  8788 Mar  2  2013 stream3.c

  /opt/gwan64/62.210.169.132_80/#62.210.169.132/csp/folder:
  total 12
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1453 Dec 21  2012 hellox.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1033 Dec 21  2012 hello.c
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1295 Dec 21  2012 argv.c

  /opt/gwan64/62.210.169.132_80/#62.210.169.132/www:
  total 36
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  100 Nov 24  2009 100.html
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1136 Mar  8  2012 csp_contact.html
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5036 Mar 24  2012 csp_comet.html
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1663 Oct 17  2012 csp_entity.html
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3834 Feb 11  2013 csp_loan.html
  drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Mar  8  2013 imgs
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7497 Mar 14  2013 index.html

  /opt/gwan64/62.210.169.132_80/#62.210.169.132/www/imgs:
  total 128
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   102 Apr  7  2011 gwan16.gif
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   202 Jun 29  2011 gwan_pw.gif
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   284 Jul  4  2011 rss.png
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   206 Jul  4  2011 gwan_rulez.gif
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   470 Aug 13  2011 errors.css
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   748 Mar 21  2012 ajax.js
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2807 Mar 21  2012 comet.js
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 81114 Oct  1  2012 OOW_new_demo.jpg
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1308 Jan 13  2013 dl.css
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10561 Jan 17  2013 style.css
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1913 Feb 18  2013 watermark.png

  /opt/gwan64/logs:
  total 20
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14344 Jan  9 18:10 gwan_2016-01-09.log
  -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  3674 Jan 10 14:32 gwan.log
```

Comment: So what do you get when you execute `ls -ltrR /opt/gwan64`? By the way, since you are executing this as root you certainly do not need the chmod 777.

Comment: Hi Law29, I added the requested data :-)

Comment: According to http://gwan.com/faq#listener the `_logs` directory should be named `logs`, but if that's not it I don't know. You might want to contact their support.

Comment: After the renaming of _logs to logs, the problem remains halas...

Comment: Any G-WAN user please ?

Comment: You can try to summon @Gil http://serverfault.com/users/107660/gil but he is "Last seen Jul 31 '15 at 9:48"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to download today, on the official web site of G-WAN, the last version 7.12.2 and all is now working perfectly !